# What's the simplest way to do string contains filtering on a numeric column with a Kendo Grid and Odata data source?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-grid, odata

I have a kendo grid with a data source:

```
{
    type: 'odata-v4',
    transport: {
        read: '/odata/Books'
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                id: {
                    type: 'number'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true
}
```

and a C# odata controller:

```
namespace What.Ever
{
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [EnableQuery]
    public class BooksController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;

        public BooksController(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var displayData = _dataService.RetrieveData().AsQueryable();

            return Ok(displayData);
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to use a string contains filter instead of the kind of clumsy numeric filter, which doesn't work as well for numeric ids as it does for numeric statistics for which it was likely intended.  Users would be able to enter only part of an Id and get back any results that contained that id.  The kendo grid needs a schema model that has a string 'type' in order to use the contains filter, rather than a number.  If I were to set the `Id` to a string type, however I would get an error when the grid attempts to execute native string functions on the field.

One solution we have is to create an IdAsString field and then do string replacement on the odata url as it comes it to set it back to 'Id' on the C#/server-side.   That way it preservers the numeric sorting, but it seems like a really inelegant solution.  For no-odata solutions that have a collections in memory, we often create a string version of each id field and then do a custom sorting on it. Otherwise if its non-odata and it uses server-side sorting we just use linq logic to implement the custom filtering.

Perhaps I can set the id to a string and convert it to a string and then implement custom sorting server-side?

This seems like a not-uncommon use case, so I wonder if there's a great solution out there.  Either by modifying some client-side part of the kendo configuration or the server-side C# odata support which uses `[EnableQuery]` attributes.

What's the best way to do string contains filtering on a numeric id, while maintaining the numeric sorting using Odata and Kendo grids/datasources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I made a string version of the id field but short-circuited the odata sorting server-side to use the original number field.  So we would get the contains filtering but also the numeric sorting rather than a string-based lexigraphical sorting.

In order to replace the string sorting server-side I removed the odata `[EnableQuery]` attribute from the controller/action and instead added a templated `ODataQueryOptions` parameter.  Using an `ODataQueryOptions` and calling its `ApplyTo` method pretty much replaces the work that the `[EnableQuery]` attribute does.  So the attribute and the parameter are largely interchangable but also mutually exclusive.  If you were to add both the odata system would apply two sets of odata options to the same result set which will likely result in an error or bizarre behavior.

So for an example controller action:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var displayData = _dataService.RetrieveData().AsQueryable();

    return Ok(displayData);
}
```

became:

```
public IQueryable<Book> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Book> options)
{
    var displayData = _dataService.RetrieveData().AsQueryable();

    _oDataSortingService.ReplaceSingleSortAsStringArguments(options);

    var results = options.ApplyTo(displayData);

    return results as IQueryable<Book>;
}
```

`ReplaceSingleSortAsStringArguments` looks for any sorting arguments with an 'AsString' postfix and then manipulates the sorting nodes of the `ODataQueryOptions` to replace the `AsString` fields with their non-postfix counterparts.

`options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes.Clear();` will clear the current. And then you can create an add an `OrderByNode` to the `OrderByNodes` list on the `OrderBy` property of the `ODataQueryOptions` object.  Like so:

```
var entityType = options.Context.ElementType as IEdmEntityType;
var edmProperty = entityType.FindProperty(newSortText);
var nodeDirection = options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes.First().Direction;
options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes.Clear();
options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes.Add(new OrderByPropertyNode(
    edmProperty,
    nodeDirection));
```

There is some code missing where I look up the current sorting arguments but you get the idea.  This should allow one to have both string filtering and numeric sorting.  The same might be possible with dates, but you might need to pass a timezone to make sure the string versions of the fields are in the same timezone as the user.